# How to use Tridion JavaScript Framework (Anguilla) to get the workflowInfo for a Component?

Tags: cme, workflow

I would like to get the workflow info for a Component using the Tridion JavaScript Framework (Anguilla).  When I create a new Component and it enters workflow, and then I use the following code it works.  But, when I refresh the GUI it does not work any longer.  How can I 're-load' this item and make sure getWorkflowInfo always gives me the good stuff?

```
var item = $models.getItem(selection.getItem(0));
var wfInfo = item.getWorkflowInfo();

if(typeof(wfInfo) != "undefined") {
    if(wfInfo.activityPerformedBy() == Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User["@ID"]) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to "load" an item before you can get workflow info, try this.

```
var item = $models.getItem(selection.getItem(0));

function itemLoaded() {
    $evt.removeEventHandler(item, "load", itemLoaded);

    var wfInfo = item.getWorkflowInfo();
    ...
}

$evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", itemLoaded);

item.load();
```